# Testing services with mocha / chai: Error testing login

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I'm writing tests for a login service. The test must pass if the login is correct. Before every test the bd is cleaned. So I first create a user and then try to login. The expected behavior is receive the status 200 in the response but instead I'm receiving status 401 which says I'm not creating the user correctly.

```
describe("Users", () => {
   beforeEach(done => {
       User.remove({}, () => {
        done();
      });
   });

describe("/POST login", () => {
    it("should return successful login", done => {
        const user = new User({
            username: "test",
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "testpass"
        });
        const user2 = {
            user: "test",
            password: "testpass"
        };
        user.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                done();
            }
            chai.request(server)
                .post("/users/login")
                .send(user2)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(res).to.has.status(200);
                    done();
                });
        });  

    });
```

Test result:

> Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 401

Any hint of what's going on here?

Comment: Well, does simulating a POSTman call with that payload (`{user: "test", password: "testpass"}`) actually successfully login the user? If not, I don't see why you'd see a `200` HTTP code for that `POST`.

Comment: Also, add the contents of the `Users` class maybe.

Comment: `username` or `user` field in your model schema? Perhaps this is why the /users/login interface reports a 401 error